# how to make print statement work in code give

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I make following print to work

```
x = input('Enter your Name : ')
y = input('Enter your School : ')
print = "Hi {}, You go to {} don't you". format (x,y)
```

Comment: Please don't use x and y as variable names.

Comment: @tea2code: What's so wrong with that? It can be improved, but it is not that big a problem.

Comment: x and y are non-descript variable names. Better names would be `name` and `school`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's just a case of learning it the right way.

Comment: The bigger problem is that the OP did not include any error messages, did not tell us what happened and what should have been the output instead. As for the 'rest of the questions' part...

Comment: As for your update, count the number of parenthesis opening and closing, make sure they match.. Your `int(...` calls are feeling unsettled today.

Comment: Please, otherwise, do not update your question with new problems. One question per post works much better. Ask a new question if you run into a new problem, but do make sure you *search* first, and include full details of the problem you encountered. Include the error messages if you got any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning to `print` instead of using it as a function. Remove the `=`, call the function instead:

```
print("Hi {}, You go to {} don't you". format (x,y))
```

Demo:

```
>>> x = input('Enter your Name : ')
Enter your Name : Martijn Pieters
>>> y = input('Enter your School : ')
Enter your School : Life
>>> print("Hi {}, You go to {} don't you". format (x,y))
Hi Martijn Pieters, You go to Life don't you
```

If you get a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` exception, you still have local variable `print` bound to a string; in an interactive Python session, simply delete that local variable:

```
del print
```

You'll have to work your way through your homework yourself; put in a little effort yourself and give your teacher something to work with. We certainly won't do your homework for you, what would be the point in that?

Comment: why the -1? This is correct (and helpful).

Comment: @AndyHayden: The initial revision made the assumption that the OP was using Python 2; I quickly corrected that, but perhaps the downvoter responded to that revision.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Did you tried it yourself? I get a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: @SantoshKumar: You ran the OP code *first* and `print` has been rebound to a string. Run `del print` *before* trying my code.

Comment: @SantoshKumar: Just for you, expanded on that error.

Comment: Great answer, great patience.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i'm trying to do it alone but some things i find a bit hard :/ .